# What's meaning of Pexp_ident use in parsetree.mli?

Tags: ocaml

I have this prog parsetreetest.ml:

```
let ()=
let filename = "test.ml" in
Location.input_name := filename ;
let readhandle = open_in filename in
let buf = Lexing.from_channel readhandle in
Location.init buf filename ;
let ast = Parse.implementation buf in
let pstr_desc=(List.nth ast 0).pstr_desc in
match pstr_desc with
|Pstr_eval (expression,attributes)->
 match expression.pexp_desc with
 |Pexp_constant constant->
  match constant with 
  |Pconst_integer (const_int,char_option)->
   Printf.printf "%s" const_int;
 close_in readhandle
```

If test.ml have only a integer,for example:1,this prog can read it and return Parsetree.

In the parsetree.mli:

```
and expression_desc =

| Pexp_ident of Longident.t loc

    (* x

       M.x

     *)

| Pexp_constant of constant

    (* 1, 'a', "true", 1.0, 1l, 1L, 1n *)
```

the Pexp_ident is paralleling to Pexp_constant,if I write parsetreetest2.ml:

```
let ()=
let filename = "test2.ml" in
Location.input_name := filename ;
let readhandle = open_in filename in
let buf = Lexing.from_channel readhandle in
Location.init buf filename ;
let ast = Parse.implementation buf in
let pstr_desc=(List.nth ast 0).pstr_desc in
match pstr_desc with
|Pstr_eval (expression,attributes)->
 match expression.pexp_desc with
 |Pexp_ident loc->
  match loc with 
  |Lident l->
   Printf.printf "%s" l;
 close_in readhandle
```

in test2.ml I write x,as the parsetree.mli example show me,then compiler with ocamlbuild,which used to compile parsetreetest.ml success,got error:

File "parsetreetest2.ml", line 14, characters 7-13:
Error: Unbound constructor Lident

I don't know why I can't do this,thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't show a definition for `Lident` so the obvious conclusion is that the constructor is undefined, which is exactly what the compiler is telling you. The case that works doesn't use `Lident`, so it doesn't have the error.

It sounds like you're working with some pre-existing files. So the thing to do might be to look around and find the definition of `Lident` and make sure it is compiled and can be found by the compiler.

If you're copying code from somewhere else, you might look to see whether there are any `open` declarations in the other code. Possibly an `open` declaration would make `Lident` available in your code.